# return value background.js to content.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

Helo, this javascript for chrome extension,
how to get value form background.js to content js.

```
    {
  "manifest_version":2,
  "permissions": [
  "storage",
  "activeTab",
  "contextMenus" 
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }...
  "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

That is my json file, i have problem this and this my background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "right_down",
      title: "Grab-Image to Content Creator",
      contexts: ["image"],
      onclick: cow
      });
});

var cow = chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info,tab) {
    // return
     cow =  info['srcUrl'];// i want Displays "url image" and proces it to content.js.
     console.log(url);
});
```

and this for content.js

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (backgroundPage) {
    console.log(backgroundPage.cow); //get value url image
});
```

i run it but no get anything, how to get return form background to other file?

Comment: Your content script code runs when the page is loaded so the variable is undefined at that time. Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your background.js, you can use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` like below:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    url: info['srcUrl'],
  });
});
```

It would send the object data (that contains your url) to given tab (specified by tab.id). You can send to all tabs with a loop.

In content script, you can receive the data from background by something like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  let {
    data,
  } = request;
  console.log(data);
});
```